# How to check distance between object that move a bit by animator and another static object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void LateUpdate()
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(cube.position, destinationTransform.position);
    }
```

The variable is my player hand and while the player is in idle state in the animator the player is stay on place but still moving a bit, for example the hand is a bit moving.

when I'm checking the distance the distance is never static it's change between 4.4 and 4.6

how can I check then the distance and make something with the hand and the cube when the distance is less then X? I tried in LateUpdate but the distance is still not accurate.

Comment: What is the type of `position` for the "cube" and "destinationTransform"?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create inside avatar's prefab an empty game object and calculate distance between them and target.
In that case distance always be static no mater what happening with hand

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrb8U.png)